# <a href=' '> not working properly

Tags: html, blogger

I have 3 blogs on blogger. One of them is linked to main domain ***helloworld.info*** whereas the other two blogs are linked to sub-domains ***blog.helloworld.info*** and ***technical.helloworld.info***.

I am using a blogger template and when I try to use  with my tabs on the top of the page wrong url is opened. Below is the code:

```
<div class='menu'>
<ul>
<li><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Blog</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='technical.helloworld.info'>Technical</a></li>
<li><a href='blog.helloworld.info'>Life Lessons</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='p/terms-of-use.html'>Terms of Use</a></li>
<li><a href='3'>About Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div><!-- end header-wrapper -->
```

Now when I click on the **Technical** tab the URL displayed is:

> www.helloworld.info/technical.helloworld.info

However, I expect it to be

> technical.helloworld.info

I am unable to find the problem.

**Whole of the code can be found here** http://pastebin.com/j7FFUM7U

Comment: Do you mean they should point to http://technical.helloworld.info ?

Comment: add a `//` before the URLs to let the browser know that they are universal. You should really make use of the `search` feature and a guy called `Google`. If you don't, you will obviously end up getting down-votes here. Please take note of this `:)` Just saying - no offence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no protocol given. As such, the href `technical.helloworld.info` could as well be a subfolder.

Quoting the comment below:

> in other words, if you leave the http:// part off the url, it treats it as a relative path and not a new domain

Comment: in other words, if you leave the http:// part off the url, it treats it as a relative path and not a new domain. So the links should be like this - `http://technical.helloworld.info`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<a href='http://technical.helloworld.info'>`

Answer (score 0):

write is as `<a href="http://technical.helloworld.info">Technical</a>`
your browser is trying to find the location you specified as a relative resource the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to append http or https in the front of the URL